# Is there a way in ajax to get it to run a php script?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need a way to make a leaderboard in a game, and, I have a php script ready to take everything in. Is there a way to use ajax to run that (with or without JQuery)? And if so, how?

Comment: The answer is yes.  Ajax hits server endpoints.  Those endpoints could be written in php.

Comment: What exactly about this question are you having trouble with?  There should be plenty of tutorials on the web about making endpoints with php. This is currently a very generic question.

Comment: See [jquery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and/or [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a leaderboard in a game, you shouldn't use constant XMLHttpRequest's or fetch(), you should use a node.js server or some other WebSockets to host all this data and send that data to them real time. If you don't want it real time, rather have it show the leaderboard as a static web page, then use an XMLHttpRequest method in JavaScript, such as

```
var xhttp;
var response;
try {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch(e) {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject();
}
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4) { //Finished Request
    if (this.status == 200) { //Found file successfully
      response = xhttp.responseText; //Or use xhttp.responseXML to get the response as XML
    }
  }
}
xhttp.open("GET","yourphpfile.php",true);
xhttp.send();
```

This will make your variable, response, have all the values you echo'd in your PHP file or the XML if you used responseXML.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad, here is some psuedo code with naming that will point you in the right direction.

**Ajax Query**

```
$.ajaz({
    type:"post",
    url:"yoururl.com/phpfile.php",
    data:yourSerializedData,
    success:function(ajaxResponse)
    {
        FunctionForResponse(ajaxResponse);
    },
    error: function(error)
    {
        console.log.(error);
    }
});
```

**PHP File** ("yoururl.com/phpfile.php")

```
if(isset($_POST['nameOfSomethingFromYourSerializedData']))
{
    //Do Something with the data posted to this via Ajax

    //return response with echo

    $ajaxResponse = "You just posted data to a PHP file with Ajax";
    echo $ajaxResponse;
}
```

With this (*not tested  notepad++ fast type*) pseudo code you should have no issues writing your own and if once writing your own you come across an issue come back with a question about that specific issue.